# Bootstrap carousel is showing all slides at once

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

It's my first time using Bootstrap Carousel, I did exactly what the documentation says, I have all four slides showing on top of each other. Any hints?

```
            <div id="madinah-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#madinah-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#madinah-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#madinah-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#madinah-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="img/mad/1.jpeg" alt="Madinah first screenshot">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="img/mad/2.jpeg" alt="Madinah second screenshot">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="img/mad/3.jpeg" alt="Madinah third screenshot">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="img/mad/4.jpeg" alt="Madinah fourth screenshot">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#madinah-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#madinah-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

I also included this JS function:

```
$(function(){
$('.carousel').carousel()
});
```

This is the header:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--- Font Awsome -->
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/4c7009c904.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- my CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

At the bottom of the  I have the following:

```
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-5i/mQ300M779N2OVDrl16lbohwXNUdzL/R2aVUXyXWA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Scrolling Nav JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would you show the header of your file? Should have the references.

Comment: When are you calling that function? Do the elements already exist at that time?

Comment: Check that you are loading bootstrap, you have missing classes I think.

Comment: I think you're right, they provided the function but I really don't know how to call it at this point! the documentation didn't say anything about it.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser's console?

Comment: @Mauro Bootstrap is loaded.

Comment: If you want to call that function automatically you can use an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression)

    $(function(){
       $('.carousel').carousel()
      }) (); 

just add the () at the end

Comment: @j08691 there is no errors.

Comment: I updated the function but still same problem $(function() {
    $('#madinah-carousel').carousel();
});()

Comment: Please check the page. it's online.. https://khaledalsibai.github.io/coursera-test/portfolio/index.html

Answer (score 5):

You have wrong classes setted in the div
it's not **div class="carousel-item"** it's just **div class="item"**

```
 <div id="madinah-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#madinah-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#madinah-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#madinah-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#madinah-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/mad/1.jpeg" alt="Madinah first screenshot">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/mad/2.jpeg" alt="Madinah second screenshot">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/mad/3.jpeg" alt="Madinah third screenshot">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/mad/4.jpeg" alt="Madinah fourth screenshot">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#madinah-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#madinah-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

I've tried that in fiddle and it's working.

Regards

Comment: Yes' it's working now, thank you so much, I wonder why the documentation listed it as div class="carousel-item" that is weird!

Comment: I've just checked, it's bootstrap v4 alpha that carousel-item class.

I used this docs from w3 schools for your carousel.
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp